# Nebensätze als Einschübe - auch nach dem Verb möglich?

Tags: subordinate-clause

Ich lese gerade eine Masterarbeit Korrektur, dabei stieß ich auf folgenden Satz:

> Der Wert statistischer Datenbestände wird beispielsweise bei der Betrachtung der Arbeitsweise des statistischen **Bundesamtes** greifbar, **des** nach eigener Aussage „führenden Anbieters qualitativ hochwertiger statistischer Informationen über Deutschland“.

Laut meinem Sprachempfinden müsste es aber:

> Der Wert statistischer Datenbestände wird beispielsweise bei der Betrachtung der Arbeitsweise des statistischen **Bundesamtes, des** nach eigener Aussage „führenden Anbieters qualitativ hochwertiger statistischer Informationen über Deutschland“, greifbar.

sein, wobei dadurch das Verständnis erschwert wird.
Ist die erste Version korrektes Deutsch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die erste Version ist nicht nur korrekt sondern auch stilistisch besser, eben weil sie besser verständlich ist. Bei der zweiten Version verliert der Leser unterwegs den Atem.

Bereits Ludwig Reiners empfiehlt in seiner berühmten "Stilfibel", überlange Satzkonstruktionen auf diese Weise besser lesbar zu machen.

Für Kenner und Genießer:

Ludwig Reiners: Stilfibel. Der sichere Weg zum guten Deutsch. C.H. Beck, 1959. Bzw. die Erstausgabe von 1951 noch unter dem Titel *Der sichere Weg zum guten Deutsch. Eine Stilfibel*.

Wurde vielfach neu aufgelegt, ist bis heute im Handel erhältlich, und ist wirklich empfehlenswert zum Training einer guten schriftlichen Ausdrucksweise. Mit vielen amüsanten Beispielen und Übungen.